# "two-thirds (of) (a) teaspoon(s) of salt"

Tags: grammar

How should I say it?

> Add **two-thirds (of) (a) teaspoon(s)** of salt and knead the dough for five minutes.

Comment: Please show the research you've already done. Also, what's the context? Is it a cookbook or a dialogue?

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer "two thirds of a teaspoon" in speech and formal writing. In the context of a recipe, however, the measurement can probably be omitted since it was probably given above in the list of ingredients:

> **Ingredients:**
>
> - ⅔tsp. Salt
> - ... other ingredients
>
> **Instructions:**
>
> ... Add salt and knead the dough for five minutes.